# Is there a plugin for firefox where I can paste in arbitrary HTML5 code and see it immediately rendered?

Tags: html

A standalone tool is welcome as well, as long as it is free.

Thanks.

Comment: "`notepad`, file->save, drag file to browser" is available on every windows system with firefox...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSFiddle is great for sandbox testing this kind of stuff. Here's the link: http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: jsFiddle is useful, but changes aren't immediately rendered.  You paste in changes and then hit the Run or Update button.  Unlike the Web Developer add-on, jsFiddle doesn't let you modify an existing web page.

Comment: Sure, but it's so close to immediate that it doesn't really matter. WebDev Toolbar is also not cross-browser, which I would expect to be very useful for anyone testing an emerging technology like HTML5.

Comment: The question specifically asks for Firefox so cross-browser purposefully wasn't part of the OP's question.  jsFiddle and Web Developer solve somewhat different problems (I regularly use both).  Which is best depends more on the nature of the thing you're working on than one is necessarily better than the other.

Comment: Ah yes, I missed that one. I tend to skim-read the title and then read the question in detail. I guess jsFiddle and WDT both go together to solve this problem quite nicely.

Answer (score 4):

You're looking for [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Answer (score 1):

[Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) works well for me. As well as this it provides a lot of other very useful development tools (change css on the fly, see computed layout, debug javascript etc).

Comment: Only really useful for Firefox. Considering this question is about an emerging technology, the OP is likely to want to test on multiple browsers. Firebug is still very nice though.

Comment: I have tried FireBug, but it seems to allow editing on per-element basis. It does not allow to edit the whole <HEAD> element, only its children, which is very incovenient. Even though it supports multiple selection, clicking the Edit button only edits the focused element. In short, it a very good tool, but not for massive editing, for tweaking - yes.

Answer (score 0):

Besides jsfiddle, I think you can simply use **HTML edit** feature of firebug, which is immediately shown in Firefox.

On the **HTML** tab, simply click **Edit**, and now paste (or write) your HTML5, then click **Edit** button another time. All done!

Answer (score 0):

The [Web Developer add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/web-developer/) for Firefox lets you directly edit the HTML or CSS of the current page and changes are immediately rendered.